# Update_batch array codeigniter with the NOW() doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, timestamp

What I want is to make a database update with codeigniter where I put a value to current timestamp:
My settings array:

```
$settingsMachineUpdateEvent[] = array(
        'id' => $eventId,
        'etid' => '5',
        'insert_by' => '2',
        'modified_date' => $currentTime
        );
```

And my $currentTime:

```
$currentTime = date_default_timezone_get();
```

And I send the update like this:

```
$this->db->update_batch('balance_events', $settingsMachineUpdateEvent, 'id');
```

My problem is the $currentTime var, I want to assign it the current time stamp so I can update my modified_date column from mysql with the current timestamp value. I also try'ed with NOW(), time(), and assign it directly from array, nothing worked, I will get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 after the update. Where is the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$currentTime = date_default_timezone_get();
```

try

```
$currentTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // for current time

$currentTime = time();  // for current timestamp
```

**Explanation:** `date_default_timezone_get()` is used to get the timezone, but in your case you need the `time` or `timestamp` to store in the table.

Comment: Enjoy the coding!!